# APPLESCRIPT - How to run multiple tasks at once? (Not 1 by 1)

Tags: macos, applescript

```
set holdthevolume to (path to resource "holdthevolume.scpt" in directory "Scripts")
run script holdthevolume

set copyfiles to (path to resource "copyfiles.scpt" in directory "Scripts")
run script copyfiles
```

Hold the volume. Is a script which is running under a "repeat". Therefore ti never ends until the app is quit. In which doing this it never passes that process to move onto the second part "copyfiles". How do i make it not care if that one has finished and move on to the next task?

the script holdthevolume.scpt is:

```
repeat
   set volume 7
   delay 0.01
end repeat
```

Comment: woops, made a mistake.

Comment: Can you show us how "holdthevolume.scpt" is structured. There may be a way to do this with a stay open application instead but i'd need to see what that script is doing.

Comment: repeat
 set volume 7
 delay 0.01
end repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to export holdthevolume.scpt as a Stay Open application and launch it, this will give you the separate thread type execution.

eg,

```
set vol_app_path to (path to resource "holdthevolume.app" in directory "Scripts")

tell application vol_app_path to launch

set copyfiles to (path to resource "copyfiles.scpt" in directory "Scripts")
run script copyfiles

tell application vol_app_path to quit
```

..and holdthevolume.app uses an idle handler instead of a loop.

```
on idle
    set volume 7
    return 0.01
end idle
```

The down side is holdthevolume.app will be visible in the doc.

Alternatively you could explore using "do shell script" with the 'osascript' command which may also work in a non-blocking way.